# Single sign-on password manager with multi-field (Firefox) support

Tags: linux, firefox, password-manager, ssh, pgp

Some of my accounts require multiple fields such as username and a separate ID in addition to a password to login. [KeeFox](http://keefox.org/) (improving the collaboration of Firefox and Keepass) supports this just fine, and I can additionally use [KeeAgent](http://lechnology.com/software/keeagent/) as replacement for `ssh-agent` to store ssh keys. The things I am currently missing though:

- GnuGP integration - ideally the sought software would also act as `gpg-agent`
- Single Sign-On - once I log in to Linux, everything should be unlocked until I lock the screen or log out again. I could probably encrypt my home directory and then use unencrypted password files, but somehow that makes my gut complain. The closest alternative I can get to is using [pam-ssh](http://pam-ssh.sourceforge.net/) which uses an SSH key to authenticate login and act as `ssh-agent` at once, and then I probably *could* use the method described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/23252/3272) to obtain RSA-signatures acting as passwords **edit** I wrote a small Python script [`ssh-agent-sign`](https://github.com/zommuter/ssh-agent-sign), though there's at least [one important issue](https://github.com/zommuter/ssh-agent-sign/issues/4) unsolved for now...